# How many cards must be drawn from a standard 52-card stack to guarantee 2 cards of the same suit? 2 cards of spades?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

A question from a chapter about counting asks this. I got the answers 14 and P(13,2) but I know these are wrong.

Comment: Consider worst case scenarios.  How many cards can you select without getting two cards of the same suit? two spades?

Comment: +1 for @N.F.Taussig's comment. This problem is purely counting/pigeonhole; there's no probability (which you tagged). It's also good to do sanity checks too. For example, $P(13,2) = 13!/(13-2)! = 156>52$, so there's clearly a flaw in the logic used to produce your second number.

Answer (score 1):

By the 5th card you will have 2 of the same suit if any suit ok. If it has to be the suit of spades, then worst case 13 cards of each hearts, diamonds, and clubs = 39 draws, so 40th draw is 1st spade, 41st is 2nd spade.